# What to do to keep glasses from slipping down?

Tags: eyeglasses

My glasses took a direct hit from a basketball a while back, and started coming loose. They used to fit me perfectly (after the [optician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optician) fiddled around with them), but now they keep slipping down my nose.

I tried bending them (*very carefully!!*) by hand (something like what my optician did when I bought the glasses), to bring the nosepieces closer to each other, and to bring the temples closer together, but this doesn't work.

**What can I do to keep my glasses from sliding down?**

....I should probably bring them back to the optician, but I don't have time to make an appointment, and if the solution is something one doesn't need training for (*very* likely, IMO), it would probably come out to be cheaper than going back to the store and having the optician fix them.

I'd rather not use glue, if I don't have to, because (1) it's messy (2) I don't want to risk jamming the moving parts (hinges, etc.) by accident.
What I'm looking for (I think) is something that's readily available that I can attach to the nosepieces of the glasses, that would increase their traction to my nose (*if that makes sense*).

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do is actually pretty simple, but is not a permanent solution.

1. Take the nosepieces of your glasses and gently bring them together.
2. Once it's smaller than the length of the bridge of your nose, make sure all screws in the glasses are as tight as possible.
3. Place the glasses on your face. The nosepiece will be a bit small.
4. Now, push down gently (but with some force) until your glasses feel to be in place.

But really, if your glasses got hit with a basketball, other things might be damaged (some glasses have springs and such that get knocked loose). Take it to your optician at your earliest convenience.

---

You could also try a dab of Elmer's school glue. It's not too sticky or painful to get off, and it works. It does look ugly though.

Alternatively, take some duck tape and tape the arms to your face. That works too.

---

**Edit to counter your edit:**

If you want traction to your nose, find some sandpaper. The finer stuff is better for this. Using a tiny bit of glue, glue a small square of sandpaper to each nosepiece. It should be tiny and relatively hard to notice, but it will provide some traction. And it'll give your optician a good laugh.

Comment: DV? Please do explain.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on Shark Tank and it seems to be what you're looking for : [Nerd Wax](http://www.nerdwax.com) .

It's made of beeswax (and maybe some other stuff), so if you have a readily available source of beeswax, you might try that instead. Put the wax on the nose pieces to give them more grip.