# How can I stop my glasses from slipping down my nose?

Tags: eyeglasses

I am currently using these glasses:

[image]

They slip a bit down my nose when I move suddenly or when I look at the ground. I have to re-adjust them and that's a bit inconvenient.

Is there anything I can do to prevent them from slipping down my nose?

P.S. I am aware of [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2200/what-to-do-to-keep-glasses-from-slipping-down) but my glasses have fixed nosepieces and that's why I'm asking this as a separate question.

Comment: Cleaning your face, and also cleaning your glasses to remove any sweat and grease will really help.

Comment: If your glasses are slipping, they're probably not adjusted properly. Take them to an optician and they'll fix them for you (in this case probably tightening the arms).

Comment: And Steve Martin's character invented a solution for this in the movie "The Jerk". https://youtu.be/i5jTH89HjTA?t=1m22s

Comment: Choose frames that fit you when buying, not just ones that you like.  Also look for plastic lenses with a higher refractive index instead of glass lenses for the weight saving.  Thinner temples helps too - they don't need to be as thick and wide as fashion implies.

Comment: If you used an optometrist for this, go back to them and explain your problem.  They have a process to adjust the earpieces so they snugly fit your head and ears.  It appears this was not performed, or not completed correctly, so go back and have them re-fitted. I'd submit this as an answer, but apparently around here doing things the right way isn't considered a life hack.

Comment: Didn't want to post an answer although it technically solved the problem. In the most hackey way. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=james+sooy&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=698&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2j8iKreDJAhXCWRoKHeaKAxkQ_AUIBygB This guy put a barbell through his nose and attaches his glasses to it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here some options that don't involve vandalizing your face.

**1. Ponytail holders**

[image]

[Stop Your Glasses from Slipping Off Your Face with Ponytail Holders](http://lifehacker.com/stop-your-glasses-from-slipping-off-your-face-with-pony-1683978219)

**2. Ear Hook**

[image]

[Anti-slip Holder for Glasses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQOLADS)

**3. Nerd Wax**

[image]

The Original Glasses Wax

Comment: They're doing it wrong in that nerdwax picture. They said you are supposed to use the side of the cylinder of wax.

Comment: I also bought some awesome silicon nose pads that adhere to the frame. Barely noticeable and seem to hold up well.

Comment: @DangerZone: Silicon makes everything better.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like a joke, but I found it works well for quite some time before needing to pull my glasses up by hand. I learned to pull my glasses up with my ears! Doing that taught me how to wiggle my ears and get children to laugh, so that might be an additional reason to learn. Dunno how I started, but I was being frustrated and started not being frustrated. Sort of an unconscious learning system.

Comment: I tried it and it is working, but only when they are slipping a little.

Comment: Whenever I try it the glasses end up going in the opposite direction.

Comment: I have a friend who (apparently without realizing) keeps making a particular strange short "grinning" face once every few minutes or so. I never asked him why. This is a possible explanation. (I haven't noticed if his ears are wiggling.)

Answer (score 10):

There's no need for extra gadgets or body mods, you simply need to make the glasses a tighter fit.

1. Tighten the screws fixing the arms to the main part of the glasses.
2. Carefully bend the arms so that fit more tightly to your head and, in particular, so the hooks on the end fit tightly behind your ears.

Comment: Exactly that. I bend my glasses to fit my head until they sit properly. If they are a bit delicate you can go to the optician and they bend them for you. If they are really thick dunk them in hot water first to get them more bendy.

Comment: This is why a lot of life hacks just seem ridiculous to me. The solution shouldn't be to buy extra gadgets or attach post-it notes(!!!) to your glasses, it should be to just get glasses that actually fit properly.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: But that's not a hack!

Comment: And I cannot get glasses to fit the bridge of my nose properly, only one pair out of the entire stock at my opticians had a bridge broad enough to fit (solution may well be to re-break my nose and set it thinner but I am not that vain, nor can I be the only one with a need for glasses and a thick nasal bridge, so I refuse surgical alteration to wear glasses on principle).

Answer (score 2):

I have always used   https://wedgees.com/   Funny name but they really work.  They always sends me more than I order so they are pretty inexpensive.  I have on my readers and sunglasses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that might work.

Cut two small rectangular pieces from the sticky area of a Post-It note.  Fold each in half, sticky side out.  Stick one to each nose piece of your glasses.

Double sided Post-It tape is also available, but most people aren't going to have it handy.

Answer (score 1):

One frequent reason for glasses slipping is perspiration.  A simple fix, assuming that is the source of the problem, is a to apply a bit of antiperspirant to each side of the bridge of the nose.

Clear and unscented would be my choice.

Comment: Make sure you use antiperspirant, and not just deodorant.  A deodorant won't stop perspiration at all.

Comment: I just tried this with a can of lynx, OMG warn people about the potentially stingy eyes, the glasses stay on but damned if I can see anything through the tears!

Answer (score 1):

Go to an optician and ask them to adjust the fit? I've done it a couple times so far, they have a machine in the back room usually.

It's legally mandated to be free in Canada, but I don't know what the rules in the US are.

Answer (score 0):

My wife swears by these [Silicone Anti-Slip Ear Grip Hook For Eyeglasses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LWQSI7I).

She says it's funny; they're something like 50 cents each, but she feels like they've changed her life.  She used to hate wearing her glasses.

(It looks like there's a similar product in Samuel's answer; I made this answer only because my wife was so happy about this exact link in particular.)

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks. As you yourself suggests, this is a duplicate product recommendations, and in general we can refer to product groups, but we try to stay away from product recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

[Rubber](http://dipheadsunite.com/) [coat](http://www.plastidip.com/) the applicable areas, e.g. places touching the nose or ears.

Lots of color choices available, which makes this a fun option! The best part is that on most surfaces, the finished material peels right off with an intentional (shall we say more than moderate?) amount of force.

Comment: Welcom to Lifehacks. Please try to stay away from product recommendations, and rather describe them in general terms!

Comment: Well, I have to wear glasses, safety glasses, burning goggles so thought I can save some money and rubber coat my nose instead.  Painful?  It wasn't half!  Effective?  Well yes and no, can wear glasses but when I try to kiss my wife while hurrying out the door for work, my nose bounces off her like a bouncy ball, had whiplash 3 times this week already....

Answer (score 0):

Glasses will often slip when I'm jogging. Got this pair of ear/spectacles hook. [image: Wedge Classic, http://betasimplicity.com/wedgeclassic.html]. Tried a few different types of rubber ear hook and this is the most comfortable so far. Here's more information,http://betasimplicity.com/wedgeclassic.html

I'm not sure whether adjusting the glass temple will work for all people. Once an optician told me that if the glass temple is adjusted properly, it will not slip. And when he turned round, I see him having ear hooks on his glasses...

Answer (score 0):

Buy lighter frames.  You have a nice Persol frame.  I have John Varvatos. I love the look, but they are somewhat heavy and, much to my frustration, frequently slide down my nose, too.  I have a friend who just got a pair of glasses with featherweight Oakley frames.  [image]  I tried them on and those babies aren't going anywhere. I will be getting a similar pair when it's time for my insurance to spring for a portion of the frame cost.